# Still empty HashSet after Exception in addAll()

Tags: java, null, addition, hashset

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>() {
        public boolean add(String arg0) {
            if (arg0 == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add null to Set");
            }

            return super.add(arg0);
        }
    };

    set.add("s0");

    Set<String> toAdd = new HashSet<String>();
    toAdd.add("s1");
    toAdd.add("s2");
    toAdd.add(null);
    toAdd.add("s4");
    toAdd.add("s5");

    try {
        set.addAll(toAdd);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(set.toString());
```

This is my code. I create a `HashSet` where you cannot add null, otherwise you will get an `IllegalArgumentException`. Then I add the `String` `"s0"` to the `HashSet` and I create a further `HashSet` to test my code with `addAll()` because `addAll()` uses the `add()` method.

Output of the code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add null to Set
    at testprogramm.TestProgramm$1.add(TestProgramm.java:17)
    at testprogramm.TestProgramm$1.add(TestProgramm.java:1)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at testprogramm.TestProgramm.main(TestProgramm.java:39)
[s0]
```

As you can see there is an `IllegalArgumentException` as planned but why is there not even one `String` of the `toAdd` `HashSet` in the `set` `HashSet`? Should not there be all strings in the `set` `HashSet` with a lower "index" of the null element in the `toAdd` `HashSet`?

Comment: `HashSet` has no order, so there are no ‘indices‘.

Comment: Yes, but there must be a kind of order to add the strings, and so there should be strings like "s1" or "s2" also in the set.

Comment: My bet is that the null value is always the first value returned by the iterator.

Comment: This could be an explanation.

Comment: @stonar96 Yes you could dig into the source of of HashMap and see how the iterator returns the values. It seems that putForNullKey places the entry in the first bucket of the map.

Comment: If you use `List<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<String>();` you get `[s0, s1, s2]` as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add null value to HashSet iterator will return null value as first element. That is why you are able to see only the first element [s0]. You can print toAdd and test it( System.out.println(toAdd.toString()))

Answer (score 1):

addAll(Collection) is method of java.util.AbstractCollection that does not catch any exception.
When a HashSet is passed with 1st element as null. The iteration is done for the first null element as this execution

```
  throws IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add null to Set")
```

So no more iteration is happening.i.e. no element is being added.

addAll method details:

```
 public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<? extends E> e = c.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        if (add(e.next()))
            modified = true;
    }
    return modified;
}
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29